# How to insert an svg as the text of a button in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

i need to create a button that closes a modal in reactnative. That button is already configured but im having trouble iserting the icon into the button.
My button component its this

```
const Boton = ({ onPress, title, styleB, styleT }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style = {styleB}
    onPress={onPress}
  >
    <Text style = {styleT}>{title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

and im using it like this

```
<View style={styles.modalContainer}>
        <View style={styles.modalContent}>
          <Text style={styles.messageText}>Es apto para tu régimen</Text>
          
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <BotonDetalle title="Ver Recetas" onPress={verRecetas} />
          </View>
          
          <Boton onPress = {onClose} styleB={styles.closeButton} styleT={styles.buttonText} title={"↓"}/>
          
        </View>
      </View>
```

instead of using the arrow symbol in the title i want to use an arrow that looks better
what is the simplest way of doing it?

i already search for other solutions but are more complex for this kind of button

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to add any package than you can look up to this [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/search/?q=arrow) that lists many emoji and it looks better than the "↓" one.

But, there are so many package for react-native icons that is easy to install and use. The one that I usually use is [`react-native-vector-icons`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#icon-component). It is easy to use you just need to replace the `<Text>` into `<Icon />` element from it.

```js
// don't forget to import
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const Boton = ({ onPress, title, styleB, styleT }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style = {styleB}
    onPress={onPress}
  >
  <Icon name="arrow-down" size={30} color="#900" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Hope it helps